# The opeartion has timed out -->Unable to resolve name in windows Container

Tags: docker, networking, iis-8, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I have a Windows Container running, but it doesn't have outbound excess
My dockerfile has base image

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1715
 //Setting IIS for my application
 Expose 443
```

I create container using below line

```
docker run -it -d --name myWebApp --cpus=2 --memory=2000m --hostname=doc --domainname=otxlab.net -p 443:443 imagename
```

My Container's ipconfig looks like this

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : doc.otxlab.net
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-0E-68-2B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a8d2:e3d5:656a:f19e%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.176.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 83891549
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-C9-D1-FD-00-15-5D-0E-68-2B
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.176.1
                                       10.194.17.21
                                       10.194.17.22
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

With above config, though I'm able to ping internal servers but not able to ping google.com
My application log errors out with below error
**The remote name could not be resolved: 'accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net'**

Setting my hostmachine's dns server as primary and secondary

```
Get-NetAdapter
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 5 -ServerAddresses 10.194.17.21,10.194.17.22
```

Now I'm able to ping google.com and also resolve above name with nslookup
But still my application logs errors out with below error
**The opeartion has timed out**

Not really sure, why the application is still not able to get response from external domain.
I have also checked my IIS logs

2020-08-19 08:14:31 **192.168.178.134** GET /WebPartPage/??? - 443 - **192.168.176.1** Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/84.0.4147.125+Safari/537.36 https://doc.otxlab.net/WebPartPage/BrowseWebPartPage.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2F%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Ftest%2F&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E20405%2E12005&wpId=g%5Fee83e176%5F1759%5F4e80%5Fb2dc%5F4d53a7aa2d85&SenderId=DD6D40620 404 0 2 46

I see the default gateway is used to make request. Is this the issue ?
How can I change it ?
I have tried setting it to my host machine (VM default gateway) but with no luck.
Should I be creating a new network for windows Container ?

Comment: Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3810) and workaround is setting DNS for daemon (use Cloudflare or Google dns servers: 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8)

Comment: Hi @Xaqron, I did try with google dns servers, but I'm not even able to ping google.com then . "Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again." .